# PDP-11 instruction set inconsistencies

Tags: pdp-11, instruction-set

The wiki page [PDP-11 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture) has a cryptic paragraph with no references or examples:

> **Inconsistent instructions**
>
> Over the life of the PDP-11, subtle differences arose in the implementation of instructions and combinations of addressing modes, though no implementation was regarded as correct. The inconsistencies did not affect ordinary use of the PDP-11.

My semi-recollection/semi-guess is that the differences could be due to variations in micro-programs dealing with auto-increments or auto-decrements of registers when a memory access interrupt occurred.

Can anyone shed light on these "subtle differences"?

<strike>The fact that *no implementation was regarded as correct* deserves another question: was there another instruction set architecture with similar  inconsistencies without an officially declared correct way of implementing the architecture?</strike>

The answer to the stricken question is likely negative; as there is no way to prove a negative except by exhaustive research, and I wouldn't want to have a virtually unanswerable question under my name, I will not post it separately, unless someone would want to answer it positively.

A contemporary example would be a difference between Intel and AMD in their handling of [a jump instruction with a data size override prefix](https://youtu.be/KrksBdWcZgQ?t=29m25s) (punchline at 32m50s).

Comment: I would suggest posting your second question as a second question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It will make sense splitting them as soon there is a concrete example of what exactly it asks about (cf. "similar inconsistencies") in the form of an answer to the first question.

Comment: THe only 'inconsitency' I can think of are extensions (like FP, etc) that have been only available on certein machines - and unlike the PC development, not enhanced machiens where sold for decades after. Same goes for certein instructions and their behaviour on muti processor memory, depending on the momory implementation. But thats (mostly) restricted to I/O access.

Comment: Review the Wikipedia entry for IBM System 360 for differences between implementations of the hardware.

Comment: @PDP11 A customary courtesy is to provide a clickable URL.

Comment: Please refer to my extended answer whch includes a clickable URL reference to instruction set differences. [https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/pdp-11-instruction-set-inconsistencies/23627?noredirect=1]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
mov r5,-(r5)
```

That moves the contents of `R5` to the address location specified in `R5` after first decrementing `R5`. The question is what gets put in the memory location? Is it the contents of `R5` before the instruction was started or is it the decremented `R5`.

For example, if `R5` contained 10 (decimal), usually the microcoded PDP-11s, would put 10 in location 9. Others, the earlier non microcoded ones, would put 9 in location 9.

---

Source: The book PDP-11 Architecture Handbook, 1983, digital, verifies this in Appendix B, "PDP-11 Family Differences". Specifically, the models 23/24, 15/20, 25/40, 60, J-11, and T-11 would pre-decrement r before using it. The 44, 04, 34, LSI-11, 05/10, 45, 70, and VAX would not.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense. Is there a chance you could add some source for further reading?

Comment: That example comes from https://github.com/gaojiechina/os_collection/wiki/PDP-11-architecture

Comment: Now that's interesting. The page you linked is a verbatim copy of the Wiki artikle about the PDP architecture from 2014 - but exactly that paragraph got removed in 29015, as 'just guesses' and quite frankly, a change that important would break many programms, while the paragraph before mentioned that 'normal programs are not affected'. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PDP-11_architecture&type=revision&diff=690440627&oldid=690440064

Comment: I'd be surprised if moving a register into itself predecremented formed part of any reasonable program. It's a bit like the old C chestnut of `a = b++ + ++b;` I could find other examples, but that was the first one.

Comment: Would be great if there are any, as this one seams to be not verified. I just went thru the manuals for the PDP11/20 (KA11 non microprogram) and 11/45 (KB11 microprogrammed) and couldn't find any hint. Same on the 1975 programming card. One would expect to find some when the difference is that obvious.

Comment: The book _PDP-11 Architecture Handbook_, 1983, **digital**, verifies this in Appendix B, "PDP-11 Family Differences". Specifically, the models 23/24, 15/20, 25/40, 60, J-11, and T-11 would pre-decrement **r** before using it. The 44, 04, 34, LS1/11, 05/10, 45, 70, and VAX would not.

Comment: Thank you; It's interesting that this difference is visible at the user level and therefore can affect ordinary use. Obviously (?), `mov r5, @-(r5)` would be affected the same way, and that instruction potentially has more sense, dealing with arrays of pointers to structures with fields pointing back to elements of the array, or some such.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The ARM architecture manual expressly says that certain such constructs are not guaranteed to behave consistently.  If the PDP-11 manual had done likewise, then such a change would only break code whose authors ignored that explicit warning.

Comment: @supercat are speculations about speculations realy woth the time?

Comment: @Raffzahn: I was responding to the "And frankly, a change that important would break many programs".

Answer (score 10):

As I remember, there were the following inconsistensies:

- Jumping to an odd address could bring different results (trap or continuing from the closest even address)
- Byte operations with the stack pointer. In some models this would be working as with any other register, decrementing/incrementing SP by one, in others only increment/decrement of SP by 2 was possible.
- Byte move to a register on some models would fill the other byte of the register with sign.
- Different behavior of some SWAB and bit mask operations, I do not remember details.

Comment: re *continuing from the closest even address* - which is closer to address 12345 -- 12344 or 12346?  :-)   As far as I recall on the 11/24, the low bit was ignored, i.e., it would be 12344.  This was widely seen as an annoying misfeature, since some bugs would not be detected.

Comment: Again as far as I recall - byte move to a register always sign-extended.  This sticks in my mind because I almost never wanted it to.

Comment: 'Trap' was correct before the last edit.  It's an "odd address trap" (because synchronous with instruction execution), not an interrupt (because not caused by an external signal). [See page 128 in this handbook](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp11/handbooks/PDP11_Handbook1979.pdf).

Comment: @dave OK, revert

Comment: Intel usage irritates me - the INT instruction is a trap, not an interrupt :-)

Answer (score 8):

Some PDP-11 family computers could address its own registers as the top 8 (16-bit) addresses in its address space. (The top 4 kwords were sometimes dedicated to an I/O page.) For example, a program running on the 05/10 model could place a short loop in R2 to R5 and execute it from those registers. On most models, however, accessing those locations would yield a time-out.

The above is item 7 in a 52-member list of architecture instructional differences within the PDP-11 family, as itemized in Appendix B, "PDP-11 Family Differences" of_PDP-11 Architecture Handbook, 1983, **digital**. Most are quite minor or obvious, such as some PDP-11s had the Extended Instruction Set (EIS) or floating point and some did not.

Comment: Differences of the kind "a program works on one platform and causes a bus error or an illegal instruction exception on another" are anything but subtle. Are there other items in the list similar to the one above?

Comment: @LeoB. Yes. For example the 4th listed variance is the behavior of **JMP (R)+** (as well as **JSR (R)+**). On some models the register would be incremented by two first, whereas other models would immediately jump to the given value of R. I checked to see if I could find a copy of this book online, but I could not find it.

Comment: I see. Then, apparently, [the self-propagating instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APDP-11#PDP-11_Self-Propagating_Instruction) 014747 `MOV -(PC), -(PC)` would have worked on some platforms but not others?

Comment: FWIW, MACRO-11 would flag the instructions that are known to cause different behaviour (error code Z), see MACRO-11 Lang Ref Manual.

Comment: I wouldn't count this as a "difference in the implementation of instructions", but rather as a difference in the addresses with special meanings (so, memory layout, not ISA).

Comment: @sendmoreinfo That's a very useful feature, indeed.

Comment: @RichF You may want to move your comment about JMP (R)+ to the answer.

Comment: Since I have not yet found an architecture ref manual online (anyone?), I'm just noting that [this J-11 manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/1173/KDJ11-A_UsersManual.pdf) lists differences in Appendix B.

Answer (score 7):

#### Instruction set differences

Retyped from DEC manual [EK-PDP94-MG-001](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/1194/EK-PDP94-MG-001_Sep90.pdf), *PDP-11/94-E System User and Maintenance Guide*, Appendix D.

| Item | 23/24 | 44 | 04 | 34 | LSI11 | 05/10 | 15/20 | 35/40 | 45 | 70 | 60 | J-11 | T-11 | VAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JMP %R or JSR reg,%R traps to 10 | X |  | X | X | X | X | X | X |  |  | X |  | X | na |
| JMP %R or JSR reg,%R traps to 4 |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  | X | X |  | X |  | na |
| SWAB does not change V |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| SWAB clears V | X | X | X | X | X | X |  |  | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| Register addresses (177700-177717) are valid program addresses when used by CPU |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  | *1* | *1* |
| Register addresses (177700-177717) time out when used by CPU; can be used by console |  | X | X | X |  |  | X | X | X | X | X |  |  | na |
| Register addresses (177700-177717) time out when used by CPU or console | X |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |
| Basic instructions noted in PDP-11 processor handbook | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| SOB, MARK, RTT, SXT instructions *2* | X | X |  | X | X |  |  | X | X | X | X | X | X | *3* |
| ASH, ASHC, MUL, DIV, XOR | X | X |  | X | X |  |  | X | X | X | X | X |  | *3* |
| Floating Point instructions in base machine |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X | X |  |  |
| MFPT instruction | X | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |
| External KE11-A option provides MUL, DIV, shift operation in the same data format |  |  |  |  |  | X | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| KE11-E option (EIS) provides MUL, DIV, ASH, ASHC. These new instructions are 11/45-compatible |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Notes:
*1.* Register addresses (177700-177717) are handled as regular memory addresses in the I/O page.
*2.* RTT instruction is available in 11/04 but is different to other implementations.
*3.* All but MARK.

Comment: Nice.  You found the list and even posted a formatted version.  Thanks!  For anyone not looking full screen -- the full width of table may not be showing.  I had to expand my window.  There is also a thin little scroll bar at the bottom of table which took me a while to notice.

Answer (score 3):

> The wiki page PDP-11 architecture has a cryptic paragraph with no
> references or examples:
>
> Inconsistent instructions
>
> Over the life of the PDP-11, subtle differences arose in the
> implementation of instructions and combinations of addressing modes,

From Bitsavers the [PDP-11 Systems Handbook 1987](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/handbooks/PDP-11_Systems_Handbook_1987.pdf), **Appendix A-PDP-ll Family Differences Table** states:

> The table that follows illustrates the issues involved in software
> migration between different members of the PDP-ll family.

This table starts with base model processors from the PDP-11's line of second generation processors (e.g. PDP-11/05) through to the early VAX systems (e.g. VAX-11/7xx series). All these processors were microprogrammed implementations of the PDP-11 instruction set. Note: only the first generation PDP-11/20 was not microprogrammed and this processor is not included in this Appendix.

The table occupies 15 pages of the manual and is broken down into the following topics:

- **Instructions or Instruction Sets** (5 Pages)
- **Memory Management and Relocation** (2 Pages)
- **Interrupts** (1 Page)
- **Buses** (1 Page)
- **Processor Status Word** (2 Pages)
- **General Purpose Registers** (1 Page)
- **Error Handling** (2 Pages)
- **Consoles and Serial Ports** (1 Page)

> Each member of the family has some small difference in the way it
> executes instructions.

The instruction set implemented on a particular site would be dependent on processor model number as well as the processor options fitted. There was:
Base Set
Extended Arithmetic Element (EAE) e.g. KE-11A
Floating Instruction Set (FIS) e.g. KE11-F
Floating-Point Processor (FPP) e.g. FP-11A
Commercial Instruction Set (CIS) or Extended Instruction Set (EIS)

For the PDP-11 the memory bus could be 16, 18 or 22 bits wide therefore the amount of physical memory that an assembly language program could address varied significantly.

Therefore moving an assembly language program between systems could be a problem. If the assembly language program was limited to the Basic Instruction Set then the differences were small.

Therefore you might want to question the statement that there were only subtle differences when the differences were described by a 15 page table.

> Any program developed using PDP-ll operating systems with higher level
> languages will migrate from one system to another with very little
> difficulty.

Missing instructions could be emulated by the systems so there was only a speed penalty. For the majority of high level applications migration could be accomplished with little difficulty.

> though no implementation was regarded as correct.

The Appendix A simply stated that "each member of the family has some small differences in the way it execute instructions." No processor was identified as having the 'correct' version. Therefore no implementation was regarded as correct.

> My semi-recollection/semi-guess is that the differences could be due
> to variations in micro-programs dealing with auto-increments or
> auto-decrements of registers when a memory access interrupt occurred.
>
> Can anyone shed light on these "subtle differences"?

The Appendix A table identifies which systems incremented addresses by one or two./

> The fact that no implementation was regarded as correct deserves
> another question: was there another instruction set architecture with
> similar inconsistencies without an officially declared correct way of
> implementing the architecture?
>
> The answer to the stricken question is likely negative; as there is no
> way to prove a negative except by exhaustive research, and I wouldn't
> want to have a virtually unanswerable question under my name, I will
> not post it separately, unless someone would want to answer it
> positively.

There were a number of manufacturers that offered systems configured with writable microprogram storage. In the IBM 360/40 the additional microcode could add additional instructions that emulated the IBM 1400 series. The DEC VAX-11/750 had a writable User Control Store option that allowed custom instructions to be implemented

Comment: With respect to the question of whether the differences were 'subtle' or not: generally, DEC programmers knew what to stay away from.  Looking at the appendix, I think the only one that was troubling was the "same source/dest register with autoinc/dev", but that was well-known.  Missing instructions weren't a big deal, you'd just define macros and assemble specifically for the processor. (Also, my stuff never needed to run on pre-EIS CPUs).

Comment: As the question concerns specifically "implementation of instructions and combinations of addressing modes", the relevant differences occupy only 5 pages., maybe 6 if interrupt handling may vary due to addressing modes.  Is 5-6 pages subtle enough for you?

Comment: High level language applications were not impacted. Most people would not have cared. Cost, performance, storage and communications would have been the focus of attention. Even a description of 'subtle' is overstating these differences. Only a limited subset of programmers working with one of the assembler implementations (e.g. PTS) would have known.

I've had to single step microcode, and hand assembled programs to run in register memory, etc., and never was concerned. I attempted to provide a reference to appropriate, source material. Decision of level of sublety I can leave to others.